# Deduping a list of lists runs afoul of the Borrow Checker

Tags: rust, duplicates, borrow-checker

I am trying to dedupe a list of lists. I already have a procedure that will dedupe a single list without a problem. However, now I want to concatenate multiple lists and dedupe at the same time and the Borrow checker is up to its old tricks.

In the below code, the only important thing to know about FeelValue is that it is `Clone` but not `Copy`. The key goal is to accomplish concatenation and deduping with only one Clone call. The end result is to return the `deduped` Vec, which must have stable ordering. It is easy to do it with two clone calls: just change `set.insert(&item)` to `set.insert(item.clone())` and alter the type of the HashSet.

I am happy to drain or otherwise mess with the `Vec`'s inside the `RefCell`s if need be.

```rust
let mut list_vecs: Vec< Rc<RefCell<Vec<FeelValue>>> > = Vec::new();

// Do something to fill up list_vecs...
// .....SNIP.....

let mut deduped: Vec<FeelValue> = Vec::new();
let mut set: HashSet<&FeelValue> = HashSet::new();
for rr_vec in list_vecs.iter() {
  let rr_vec_b = rr_vec.borrow();
  for item in rr_vec_b.iter() {
    if set.insert(&item) {
      deduped.push(item.clone());
    }
  }          
}
```

The error is:

```
`rr_vec_b` does not live long enough

borrowed value does not live long enoughrustc(E0597)
```

Here is a similar routine that successfully dedupes a single list.
In the folowing, the definition of list is: `list: &Vec<FeelValue>`

```rust
|list| { 
  let mut set: HashSet<&FeelValue> = HashSet::with_capacity(list.len());
  let deduped: Vec<FeelValue> = list
    .iter()
    .filter(|item| set.insert(item))
    .cloned()
    .collect();
  FeelValue::new_list(deduped) 
}
```

I just can't think of a way to chain a list of lists together into a single iterator, or I could probably use the same approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't with the borrow checker *per se*, its with `RefCell`. The `Ref` returned from `borrow()` *must* stay in scope for the duration of any references derived from it.

One trick is to collect the `Ref`s from all the `RefCell`s into a `Vec` so that all stay in scope while iterating over the references:

```
let list_vecs: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Vec<FeelValue>>>> = Vec::new();
let list_vec_refs: Vec<Ref<Vec<FeelValue>>> = list_vecs.iter().map(|v| v.borrow()).collect();

let mut deduped: Vec<FeelValue> = Vec::new();
let mut set: HashSet<&FeelValue> = HashSet::new();
for rr_vec in list_vec_refs.iter() {
    for item in rr_vec.iter() {
        if set.insert(&item) {
            deduped.push(item.clone());
        }
    } 
}
```

See it working on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e60810e4a76747863c5fffc78b834296).